# Does the Federation ever establish full relations with the Tamarians?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tng, star-trek-voyager

After the *Star Trek: The Next Generation* episode "Darmok", does the Federation ever establish open relations with the Tamarians?

Non-canon sources are welcome.

If so, how do they establish a form of communication with them?

Comment: Start with “Dathon and Picard at El-Adrel”, and build from there.

Answer (score 4):

According to Memory Beta the Federation and the Children of Tama do establish relations. This is not canon.

> The Federation encountered the Tamarians seven times prior to 2368,
>   but were never able to break the language barrier. In that year,
>   Tamarian Captain Dathon beamed himself and Starfleet Captain Jean-Luc
>   Picard of the USS Enterprise-D to the surface of planet El-Adrel IV,
>   in hopes that a shared conflict would lead to mutual understanding and
>   friendship. During this encounter, it was determined that the
>   Tamarians communicated exclusively through cultural metaphors. Though
>   Dathon was killed on the planet, the contact marked the opening of
>   communication between the two cultures. (TNG episode: "Darmok")
>
> The progress made in relations with the Tamarians following this
>   breakthrough was considered one of the noteworthy accomplishments of
>   Federation President Jaresh-Inyo and his administration. (ST novel:
>   Articles of the Federation)
>
> Roxana Novac was a linguist assigned to the Federation's Tamarian
>   liaison office, and did much work in understanding the Tamarians'
>   language. (SCE eBook: War Stories, Book 1)
>
> In 2381, the Tamarian Doctor Sharak was assigned to the USS Voyager as
>   CMO for its return mission to the Delta Quadrant. (VOY novel:
>   Unworthy)

Comment: References or citations?

Comment: @Daft: aren’t they in the quote? Specifically “ST novel: Articles of the Federation”.

Answer (score 4):

There's a recurring character in ST:Lower Decks, [Keyshon](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Kayshon) who is a member of the species Tamarian.

> Lieutenant junior grade Kayshon was a male Tamarian who lived during the late 24th century. He was the first member of his species to serve in Starfleet, and worked as an operations division security officer.

So, by the time of ST:LD there must have been established relations between the two cultures.

Answer (score 1):

#### No, there has never been any official relationship between the Federation and the [Tamarians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Tamarian)

> Although the species was encountered a total of seven times in the hundred years after first contact, **formal relations were unable to be established, due to the complexity and provincial nature of the Tamarian language** – which was entirely composed of metaphors derived from their collective experience and mythology.